# SharePoint -show list data in custom HTML/ CSS

Tags: sharepoint

I have a News list and I am requiring to show the News data (Date, Title and Description) in custom HTML/ CSS.

I am not sure of my options. Do I need a custom web part? A custom view?

Thank you very much for your help.

EDIT:
I am using WSS 3.0 and I will then upgrade to MOSS 2007 -thank you.

Comment: Are you using SharePoint 2010 or MOSS 2007? SharePoint 2010 views leverage XSLT so you could look at deploying a custom fldtype.xsl file to the hive to handle the render of your field. You could also use a List View webpart (Dataview in MOSS) in SharePoint Designer to render your data whichever way you choose.

Your question is a little ambiguous, do you need to change the way it looks in SharePoint forms and views, or are you looking to surface it in another way with the custom html/wss (i.e. a WebPart in another location)

Comment: I am using WSS 3.0 and I will then upgrade to MOSS 2007 -thank you.

Comment: Then as Vladi suggested below, Dataview webpart is your best bet with custom XSLT.

Best of luck,
Shane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have various options.

If you want to use it only in one place, use the dataview webpart as Vladi suggests. If you want to reuse it, you can still create new XSLT web parts and copy the XLST code.

If you want to make it comfortable for the customer to add a webpart here and there on his own, you should develop your own web part.

If you want your view to be available over the default page of the list, you need a custom view. The advantage of this is that you can use your view whereever you display the list (using a ListViewWebPart). On the other hand it probably takes the most effort to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a dataview web part available in SPD. You can just right-click on a regular list web part and turn it into XSLT web part. Then you can modify it as you like